# ARCore losing tracking when camera is obscured & should recalibrate

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

When the camera is obscured, the AR system loses track of the position of gameobjects and player should recalibrate the surface to make the game objects appear again.

Players can accidentally obscure the camera anytime, so this is not desirable.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, so that the gameobjects reappear in their original positions after the camera is un-obscured?

[Here's a video describing the issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AdnhHJ3cJCVngbakJTn-0lDgROeVOjWD/view)

Thanks!

-Jake

Answer (score 0):

I've never had this behavior, my guess is you need a larger space with more track-able distinguishable objects.

It's not got enough to to realise that it's looking back at the same place.